# How to insert element in array without using any builtin functions

Tags: python

How to insert a element in an array without using a builtin functions.

I have tried it with builtin functions

```
print("INSERTION:")
a = []
n = int(input("ENTER THE LENGTH OF AN ARRAY:"))

for i in range(n):
    x =int(input("ENTER THE NEXT VALUE:"))
    a.append(x)
print(a)
```

I am getting my expected result, but i want same result without using any builtin functions as we use to do in java.

Comment: You're going to have to use built-in functionality. It's no big accomplishment to do it restricting yourself to only the built-in functionality accessed without a method name.

Comment: Do you mean without using the `.append()` list method specifically? Because `print()`, for example, is a 'built-in' function.

Comment: @MurrayW yes bro without using append and insert function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("INSERTION:")

a = []
n = int(input("ENTER THE LENGTH OF AN ARRAY:"))

for i in range(n):
    x = int(input("ENTER THE NEXT VALUE:"))
    a += [x]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you're not using functions if you do

```
a = a + [x]
```

but this will be slower and will recreate `a` (i. e. its identity will change) every time.

Comment: you are right but actually i wanted to do it without functions. Thanks for the answer.